# How do I input two views in a template

Tags: django

I am trying to create a template that contains a form that creates something and a list of those somethings.If I have the views

```
def list_of_something(request):
    list1=something.objects.all()
    return render(request , 'index.html' ,{'list1':list1})
def post_something(request):
    form_class=SomethingForm
    if request.method="POST":
        form=form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        .........
        ........
        ........
    return render(request, 'post_something.html', {'form': form,})
```

This is what I have done.

1. I have tried the `include` putting `{% include "post_something.html" %}` into index.html, it loads the post_something.html but when it gets to  `{{form.as_p}}`it doesnt load it?
2. I have checked out Class-based view,but i dont know how to use it to do the above.

UPDATE
Thanks to the answers below.What I did was add `{% include "post_something.html" %}` to index.html.and pass the name of the form to the view return `render(request,'index.html,{'list1':list1,'form':SomethingForm()})` .
And additionally,point your form action attribute to post_something view and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post_something.html` is just the name of the template, you still need to pass in the form. I'm assuming you're trying to show the `list_of_something` view so you need to include the form in the context data of that view.

```
return render(request , 'index.html',{'list1':list1, 'form': SomethingForm()})
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I will try it out

Comment: With your solution it is showing the form on index.html but the logic in the view post_something() is not there.The form just accepts values and click on submit,it is gone..

Comment: @Bolaji You should change the form's `action` attribute in the template, so that it submits the form data to the `post_something` view.

Comment: @Bolaji - That is a separate issue to the one you asked in your question - for which you should ask a new question about if you are unable to resolve it yourself (include what you have tried and researched). If either of these answers solved *this* issue, you should consider accepting it

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the contents of `post_something.html` will be merged to `index.html` when you use `{% include %}` tag. Now you need to pass all the variables in the merged template from your view. It should be like this:

```
return render(request, 
              'index.html',
              {'list1':list1, 'form': form})
```

You can define the `form` based on your business use case.

Comment: Thank you very much.I will try it out

Comment: @sayse With your solution it is showing the form on index.html but the logic in the view post_something() is not there.The form just accepts values and click on submit,it is gone..